# Pagenumbers aligned raggedleft in scrartcl with tocstyle?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

When trying to typeset a table of contents with `KOMAscript`and `tocstyle`(alpha 0.2d), I finally managed to change the font of the pagenumbers (like the rest of the document to CMSS) with `\settocfeature{pagenumberhook}{\changefont{cmss}{m}{n}}`,
however now the page numbers are aligned at the left and not at the right side!
[image: screenshot bad]

So how can I change that back to an alignment on the right side of the page numbers like that, but with the sans serif font?
[image: screenshot good]

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{ \fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\usepackage[]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{classic}
%\settocstylefeature[1]{entryvskip}{10pt}
%\settocstylefeature[2]{entryvskip}{3pt}
%\settocstylefeature[1]{entryhook}{\bfseries}
\settocfeature{pagenumberhook}{\changefont{cmss}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}

\changefont{cmss}{m}{n}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your definition of `\changefont`, i.e change

```
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{ \fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
```

Comment: interesting what a little space can do... Indeed that helps. :-) Thank you very much!